# Ragweed that has lost its' bloom and now has a cott0n type substance

Tags: diseases

Why does ragweed develop a cotton type of substance before it had a yellow flowers. It did have worms which I took care of with water.

Comment: Are you sure it is ragweed? Ragweed flowers are very tiny, hard to see any colour which is usually described as "greenish". Goldenrod however (for example) has visibly yellow flower heads and will produce a cottony type of hairy down with the seeds.

Comment: pictures please